# How can I write a regular expression to validate my HTML input tag?

Tags: regex, html, input

I want to specify a pattern for my `<input>` tag such that it matches any string having length 7, starting with `ab-` followed by 4 digits.

How would I write a regular expression for this?

Comment: pattern="[A|a][B|b][-][0-9]{4}" is this correct....?

Comment: @NicolasTyler He's not asking about parsing HTML, he's asking about using a regular expression to validate an `<input>` tag client-side.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[The pattern you use in your comment is correct](http://jsfiddle.net/9Nf69/) - just make sure to keep it within a `<form>` tag with a submit button.

```
<form>
    <input type="text" pattern="[A|a][B|b][-][0-9]{4}">
    <input type="submit">
</form>
```

Answer (score 1):

A regex to match `ab-` followed by 4 digits would look like:

```
ab-\d{4}
```

Or for case insensitive matches:

```
[Aa][Bb]-\d{4}
```